# Webpack, resolving jQuery dependency in a vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, zurb-foundation

this is my `webpack.config.js` file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const parts = require('./webpack.parts');

const PATHS = {
    scripts: {
        home: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'app', 'home'),
        upload: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'app', 'upload')
    },
    styles: {
        home:  path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'app', 'home', 'styles.scss'),
        upload: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'app', 'upload', 'styles.scss'),
        commons: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'app', 'commons', 'styles.scss')
    },
    vendor: ['jquery', 'foundation-sites'],
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build')
};

const common = {
    entry: {
        home: [PATHS.scripts.home, PATHS.styles.home],
        upload: [PATHS.scripts.upload, PATHS.styles.upload],
        // app's common shared parts, for the moment just styles
        commons: PATHS.styles.commons
    }
    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
    },
    stats: {
        // Nice colored output
        colors: true
    }
};
module.exports = function(env) {
    if (env === 'production') {
        return merge(
            common,
            {
                devtool: 'source-map',
                output: {
                    // This is used for code splitting. The setup
                    // will work without but this is useful to set.
                    chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js',
                    publicPath: '/public/',
                    // Production file name
                    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
                }
            },
            parts.clean(PATHS.build),
            parts.setFreeVariable(
                'process.env.NODE_ENV',
                'production'
            ),
            parts.extractBundle({
                entries: PATHS.vendor,
                name: 'vendor'
            }),
            parts.setupStyles(),
            parts.setupScripts()
        );
    }
[...]
```

And in my `wepack.parts.js`

```
exports.extractBundle = function(options) {
    const entry = {};
    entry[options.name] = options.entries;

    return {
        // Define an entry point needed for splitting.
        entry: entry,
        plugins: [
            // Extract bundle and manifest files. Manifest is
            // needed for reliable caching.
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: [options.name, 'manifest'],
                minChunks: Infinity,
                // (with more entries, this ensures that no other module
                //  goes into the vendor chunk)
            })
        ]
    };
};
```

As you can see, I try to generate a separate bundle with my vendors libraries, in this case jquery and foundation, but when the latter is loaded in the bundled vendor file, an error of type: ***"jQuery is not defined"*** is thrown.
I can see in the vendor bundle code that the all foundation lib is wrapped in an *IIFE* of type `(function($){})(jQuery)`, so it tries to access to the global jQuery object.

Comment: Use `defer` attribute on the script.

Comment: Your .html file has reference to your vendor bundle?

Comment: yes, but i don't think the problem is in the script inclunding in the html, but in the way webpack generates the vendor file